# chromium web views don't render properly on successive dialog fragments with direct-loaded html

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat, chromium, android-dialogfragment

I have an activity that displays a series of DialogFragments.  My DialogFragment class inflates a WebView, loads some HTML via loadDataWithBaseURL() then adds it to a ViewGroup in the dialog layout.

The first time the DialogFragment is displayed the html renders properly.  The second time, however, it renders improperly and is more-or-less unreadable.  See the screen shots.  Some observations:

1. This only happens on Android 4.4+, i.e. new-style Chromium WebViews.
2. It seems to only happen with certain HTML.  So far I haven't been able to figure out what's special about the HTML that's failing to render.
3. It only happens on *successive* loads of the DialogFragment.  The first time it's displayed the HTML renders correctly.
4. It only happens with loadDataWithBaseURL().  When I take the exact same HTML, host it somewhere, then load it over the network via WebView.loadURL() it renders correctly every time the DialogFragment is displayed.

I'm at the end of my wits with this one.

[image: correctly rendered]

[image: incorrectly rendered]

Comment: Sorry but it's not obvious to me what the rendering glitch is. Is it the second screenshot? Is the text missing? Are you using web fonts?

Comment: The first image is the correct rendering.  The second one is what it does the 2nd time it's loaded.  I think it's some subtle feature of the HTML I'm being passed (from a service call).  Possibly character encoding related.  When I capture the HTML and read it from a local file, on the device, it renders correctly, but when I use the exact string I'm given by my backend service it doesn't render.  So I think I must be altering the HTML somehow during the "capture" process.  Again, though, this is definitely Chromium-related since 4.2.2 doesn't have the weird behavior.

Comment: Can you use DevTools to inspect the contents of the WebView when it's not working and check that everything looks OK? Also, what's the exact loadDataWithBaseURL call you're making?